# Is bytecode aware of Java Version

Tags: java, jvm, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Sorry if this is a daft question I haven't managed to find a straight answer.

I have compiled a program written with Java 9 features and produced a .jar.

The nature of the program is that I need it running on two machines at once, one is running java 8 and one is running Java 9.  My program is not working, specifically jdk.incubator.httpclient module is failing to send a HttpRequest from one machine to the other.

Updating the JDK8 machine to 9 is not an option.

My questions is, once it all becomes bytecode does it matter?  Will there be bytecode in the Java 9 produced jar that the Java 8 JVM can't understand?

Possibly worth noting I have to run the jar with `java -jar --add-modules=jdk.incubator.httpclient` to make use of the new java 9 incubator module httpclient

I understand a smart solution would be to make sure the firewall's on both sides allow these two to talk, however I would like to know the answer to the above as well!

Thanks in advance.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
2018-01-09 01:15:57.410  INFO 4656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.s.controller.MessageController       : [TO http://192.168.1.64:8080/send] Hello Bob it is Jim!
2018-01-09 01:18:08.551 ERROR 4656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.s.service.MessagingService           : send: unable to send request 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.PlainHttpConnection.connect(PlainHttpConnection.java:142) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Http1Exchange.sendHeadersOnly(Http1Exchange.java:136) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Exchange.responseImpl0(Exchange.java:298) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Exchange.responseImpl(Exchange.java:245) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.Exchange.response(Exchange.java:121) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.MultiExchange.response(MultiExchange.java:154) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at jdk.incubator.httpclient/jdk.incubator.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:234) ~[jdk.incubator.httpclient:na]
    at com.example.simplemessenger/com.example.simplemessenger.service.MessagingService.send(MessagingService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.simplemessenger/com.example.simplemessenger.controller.MessageController.sendMessage(MessageController.java:71) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at spring.webmvc@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.websocket@8.5.23/org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.web@4.3.13.RELEASE/org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [na:na]
    at tomcat.embed.core@8.5.23/org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]

2018-01-09 01:18:08.552  INFO 4656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.e.s.controller.MessageController       : failed to send
```

Comment: Java8 runtime cannot run Java9 compiled code. It’ll give you an error about class versioning.  Just compile them both to be Java8 compatible.  That said, you probably would learn this with some basic debugging - if it launches but “doesn’t work”, debugging should be your first step.

Comment: @Krease On that note, could you add to it how do you compile the incubator module with Java8?

Comment: @0zero The exception would need some debugging from your end to explain what cause it. Or maybe try sharing a reproducible piece of code and steps for the same.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with incubator yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. The tool `javap` can be used to see this, on Java 8

```
$ javap -v Hello.class | grep "version"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
```

And on Java 9, you'd see

```
  minor version: 0
  major version: 53
```

However, you can use the compiler flags `-target` and `-source` to make the Java 9 compiler produce Java 8 compatible code.

```
$ javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8 Hello.java
```

However, that new *incubator* may not have been **backported** to Java 1.8; in which case, I would suggest the best bet is to use [apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) - that should work on both.

Comment: Repeating the same question, could you add to it how does one compile the incubator module with Java8? I am a little puzzled on how would it compile with previous JDK version.

Comment: @nullpointer, He said that he used two machines - I'm sure one with JDK 9 installed..

Answer (score 2):

There's two different components to this question. The first issue is that as others have already mentioned, classfiles contain a version tag and JVMs will refuse to run any classfiles with a version number that is too high, which means that Java 8 JVMs will reject classfiles containing the Java 9 version code (the reverse however is perfectly fine).

The more interesting question is whether your code would work if you manually edited the version code to Java 8. In this case, it depends. At the bytecode level, the only notable changes in Java 9 were related to modules and packages. If you don't use modules, your code should still work on Java 8, assuming that all of the libraries it relies on are also available in Java 8.

Java 9 also added a couple of attributes for modules, but these are not important for runtime behavior except when using reflection and the JVM will ignore attributes it doesn't recognize, so this won't stop your code from running under Java 8.

So tl;dr; is that your code should work under Java 8 if you don't use modules, assuming you fix the version byte. However, that's a lot of trouble to go to when you can just pass the `-source` and `-target` flags to `javac` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Well, not using `-source 1.8` but patching the class file version allows you to use `private` methods in interface, for example… Also some other syntactical improvements do not actually depend on the target bytecode version, e.g. `try(existingVariable) { … }` or `new GenericClass<>() { … }`.

Answer (score 1):

> My questions is, once it all becomes bytecode does it matter? Will there be bytecode in the Java 9 produced jar that the Java 8 JVM can't understand?

Yes, the JVM running Java 8 will not be able to run the Java 9 code. You will need to compile it with Java 8 otherwise.

Comment: On that note, could you add to it how do you compile the incubator module with Java8? Also, this more or so is just a comment without a reason as to why it won't be able to run the Java9 code.

Comment: afaik that won't be possible, java 9 features cant be compiled by java 8 compiler

Comment: Your answer read *"You will need to compile it with Java 8."* .. hence curious to know.

Comment: I will now refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160589/4727762 , Antimony has answered far more eloquently than I could. Put simply, you cannot use incubator modules with Java 8

Comment: @RahulGupta yeah that's why I'm trying to answer